# how to download html source android

Tags: android, html

I want to download html source from this site "www.varzesh3.com" with android
but it doesn`t show anything in 'str' variable
here is my code:

```
private String DownloadText2(String URL)
{
    int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //e1.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }

    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
    int charRead;
    String str = "";
    char[] inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
    try {
        while ((charRead = isr.read(inputBuffer))>0)
        {
            //---convert the chars to a String---
            try{
                String readString =
                        String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0, charRead);
                str += readString;
                inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
            }
            catch (Exception ex){}
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: you do not now whether str is returning or "" un-comment the e1.printStackTrace() and run it again and copy and paste the logcat output as than we will both see which return is getting triggered

Comment: error accure at this line

Comment: in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);